# How to disable previous time in UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, datepicker

I want to disable previous time ie before current time from datePicker,**As in date picker we can use minimum Date to do this**.how could we do the same with time picker.

Here is the Code.`

```
  timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:timePicker];
  float tempHeight = timePicker.frame.size.height;
  timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0,200 ,self.view.frame.size.width , tempHeight);
  timePicker.hidden = YES;
  timePickerFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init ];
  [timePickerFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; 

  **timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;**
  timePicker.minuteInterval=15;
```

`

Thanks in Advance Please suggest me if any way to perform this.

Comment: Time Picker? What do you mean? What class are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

In the default UIDatePicker minimum date can be set and the date property has both date and time values and you can set it there itself

```
   [datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Here

```
[NSDate date]
```

gives current date

Comment: this thing is for displaying date only its not work for displaying time.As i read on Apple documentation MinimumDate Property does not work with UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer. I am using Date picker like this :  timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;

Answer (score 1):

So you want to disable previous time from current time.

```
timePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

this sets the time to current time, but i don't think you can disable the previous time.

Answer (score 1):

By This method you can provide alert to user if he/she selected the past time time. Condition is that you already placed a check on minimum date as current day.

```
func handleTimePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let timeFormatterHour = NSDateFormatter()
    let timeFormatterMinutes = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatterHour.dateFormat = "hh"
    timeFormatterMinutes.dateFormat = "mm"
    let InputTimeHourString = timeFormatterHour.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    let InputTimeMinutesString = timeFormatterMinutes.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    let InputTimeHourInt = Int(InputTimeHourString)!
    let InputTimeMinutesInt = Int(InputTimeMinutesString)!
    let calculatedInputMinutes = (InputTimeHourInt * 60) + InputTimeMinutesInt

    let TodayTime = NSDate()
    let TodayTimetimeFormatterHour = NSDateFormatter()
    let TodayTimetimeFormatterMinutes = NSDateFormatter()
    TodayTimetimeFormatterHour.dateFormat = "hh"
    TodayTimetimeFormatterMinutes.dateFormat = "mm"
    let TodayTimeInputTimeHourString = TodayTimetimeFormatterHour.stringFromDate(TodayTime)
    let TodayTimeInputTimeMinutesString = TodayTimetimeFormatterMinutes.stringFromDate(TodayTime)
    let TodayTimeInputTimeHourInt = Int(TodayTimeInputTimeHourString)!
    let TodayTimeInputTimeMinutesInt = Int(TodayTimeInputTimeMinutesString)!
    let TodayTimecalculatedInputMinutes = (TodayTimeInputTimeHourInt * 60) + TodayTimeInputTimeMinutesInt

    if TodayTimecalculatedInputMinutes - calculatedInputMinutes < 0
    {
        let shownDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        shownDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        self.txtTimeEvent.text = shownDateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
    else
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Time Selection Problem", message:
            "You cannot select the Past time", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let shownTime = NSDate()
        let shownTimeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        shownTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
         self.txtTimeEvent.text = shownTimeFormatter.stringFromDate(shownTime)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift : Add this line in your Picker Function.its Only allow future Time.

My_Pickername.minimumDate = NSDate()

Answer (score 0):

You posted your question two years ago but this may help anyone who will face this issue, I had the same problem today, and here's the solution: 
It doesn't really disable previous dates, but if a user selects a previous date, the above function will display an alert and reset the UIDatePicker to the current date :

Swift 4 :

```
@IBAction func dateChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let dtp = sender as! UIDatePicker
    if Date() <= dtp.date {
        print ("correct date")
    } else {
        dtp.date = Date()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You have to choose a correct date", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```